# Extracting integer from a tuple list containing a mix of characters and integers

Tags: python, tuples, abaqus

I would like to extract an integer(30) from a tuple list as shown below which comes after the set "vertices". The code has to have some logic to look for after vertices.

`(mdb.models['model-3'].rootAssembly.instances['Circular_knit - 2, 3, 3-1'].vertices[30], (-3.61088101472848e-14, 5.0, -3.95139073393513e-16))`

I found examples to extract this integer when the tuple is comprising only in integers. My case here is that it is after a specific set of character("vertices") that I want to extarct the integer value('30').
I would appreciate any advise on this.

```
>>>v
[mdb.models['model-3'].rootAssembly.instances['Circular_knit - 2, 3, 3-1'].vertices[30], (-3.61088101472848e-14, 5.0, -3.95139073393513e-16)]
>>> v[0]
mdb.models['model-3'].rootAssembly.instances['Circular_knit - 2, 3, 3-1'].vertices[30]
k=v[0]
k=str(k)
>>> i=0
>>> num_list = [int(i.split('[')[1]) for i in k]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You will probably want to use regular expressions (sometimes called regex). Please provide any code you have tried. I use this website to test regex expressions. https://regex101.com/ This website will not be a good resource to teach your how to use regex however.

Comment: @Correy Koshnick: I used some reference from the example here. listA = ['Mon-2', 'Wed-8', 'Thu-2', 'Fri-7']

# Given list
print("Given list : " + str(listA))

# Extracting numbers
num_list = [int(i.split('-')[1]) for i in listA]

# print result
print("List only with numbers : ",num_list)                          https://www.tutorialspoint.com/extract-numbers-from-list-of-strings-in-python

Comment: What is `type(v[0])`?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel "v" is the tuple. v[0] is the first element of the tuple

Comment: Maybe you should actually learn how to use the third-party library that generated this object, instead of turning that object into a string and pulling information out of it? It took me like two minutes to figure out you're using something called `abaqus`, and there's a wealth of documentation for how to use it and access these set elements online (I've never used `abaqus` before).

Comment: The issue between the example from tutorialspoint and your example is that 'Mon-2' is a string, but mdb.models['model-3'].rootAssembly.instances['Circular_knit - 2, 3, 3-1'].vertices[30] is an object (which is not a string) and so the method in that tutorial is not going to work. There might be a way to access the data from that object directly, but I've never worked with that library (mbd). Maybe check their documentation. If you're lucky this might work (as a total guess) `v[0].verticies`

Comment: @PaulM. : i will try to use the abaqus forum. I have gone through the documentation but haven't found any methodology for what I want to use it for. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @CorreyKoshnick: Thank you for your suggestions.v[0].vertices did not work. I will keep trying. thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Still haven't answered what `type(v[0])` is. Also try `dir(v[0])` and `help((v[0]))`. Oh and `v` is a list (note square brackes) and not a tuple which uses parentheses.

Comment: Why are they not taught to use the [interactive prompt](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode) to their advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Always look at the documentation first: it can actually save you a lot of time!

Lets split your object `mdb.models['model-3'].rootAssembly.instances['Circular_knit - 2, 3, 3-1'].vertices[30]`:

- [`mdb`](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch30pyo01.html) - high-level Abaqus model database object. Among other members it has a container `models` which contain all models of your the actual database;
- [`.models['model-3']`](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch33pyo01.html) - Model object with the name 'model-3'. Among it's members you can find `rootAssembly`.
- `.rootAssembly` - a root object for all your instances (approximately as `model` object is a "root" for all your parts);
- [`.instances['Circular_knit - 2, 3, 3-1']`](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch06pyo04.html#ker-partinstance-instance-pyc) - an Instance object which is an instance of one of your Part objects. It contains many members and one among them is `vertices` container (Note that if you are working with an orphan mesh you will have only nodes, but no vertices).
- [`.vertices[30]`](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch07pyo15.html) - finally here you are accessing the vertex under the index '30', so as a result, you have the Vertex object. Any vertex object has several members and one of them is `index`.

So, the answer to your question will be:

```py
v[0].index
```